# iGFX passthrough to Ubuntu 16.04 VM from Windows Server 2019 Hyper-V

Tags: windows, intel-graphics, virtualization, hyper-v

I'm trying to pass-through Intel integrated graphics from Windows Hyper-V to Ubuntu 16.04 Virtual Machine. I used the DDA method to perform the pass-through. VT-d is enabled in the BIOS.

The Ubuntu VM is able to detect the iGFX as per "lshw -C display" (output below) command but when the i915 module is loaded it is not used by anything on the system.

Looks like the video driver that is in use/loaded is llvmpipe as see in 
System Settings->Details->Overview window

**Question: How to enable the iGFX in Ubuntu VM?**

```
$sudo lshw -C display
  *-display UNCLAIMED     
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Sky Lake Integrated Graphics
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1
       bus info: pci@88fe:00:00.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:f0-ef iomemory:f0-ef memory:ff0000000-ff0ffffff memory:fe0000000-fefffffff memory:c0000-dffff
```